# Should i use pthread_kill over pthread_cancel

Tags: c

I am compiling an project [here is link of project on github](https://github.com/axel-download-accelerator/axel/)

Here is c source code containing `pthread_cancel` in line 620 and 690 [Click here for Source Code](https://github.com/axel-download-accelerator/axel/blob/master/src/axel.c)

But I am compiling this tool in my android phone and this project containing `pthread_cancel` function but as we know `pthread_cancel` is not available in Android libc but `pthread_kill` is. So my question is that should I use `pthread_kill` over `pthread_canel`.

It will be right patch for this project ?
Also I want to know all possible problems which can be arised by use of pthread_kill instead of pthread_cancel

And if non of them should be used so then what should I use or do to compile this project on android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use pthread\_cancel and not pthread\_kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438536/when-to-use-pthread-cancel-and-not-pthread-kill)

Comment: A good choice woul be neither.

Comment: If none of them should be used so how can I make this project workable on android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a child thread in C (Android NDK)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891552/how-to-kill-a-child-thread-in-c-android-ndk)

Comment: *If none of them should be used so how can I make this project workable on android* Properly redesign the project. I wouldn't call any code that relies on being able to use `pthread_cancel` "workable". From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html):  "The `pthread_cancel()` function shall **request** that `thread` be canceled."  Also, see [2.9.5 Thread Cancellation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_05), esp. "use of ... return, ... without doing ... results in undefined behavior." et al.

Comment: (cont) First, you can't guarantee that a thread can be cancelled.  You can only **request** that it be cancelled.  And yes, per POSIX if you don't properly handle thread state, simply calling `return` from a function can cause undefined behavior.  Read the POSIX standard on thread cancellation - there are many, many ways to invoke undefined behavior if you use `pthread_cancel()`.  Anyone using POSIX threads who has the skills to properly use `pthread_cancel()` wouldn't have to ask any questions about it - they'd be writing the answers.